# Reform of math symbols for high school texts

Tags: reference-request, math-history, education

I am looking for references to papers and resources related to reforming math symbols for introductory courses at middle or high school level. Pointers to other forums also welcome.

Eidt:

For example suggesting to use $]a,b[$ for an open interval to  avoid confusion with ordered pair. Or tweaking with current symbols to make them user-friendly for a beginner.

Comment: what does "reforming math symbols" mean?

Comment: "Reforming math symbols"?

Comment: do you mean like using $\tau=2\pi$?

Comment: @DanielRust for example suggesting to use $]a,b[$ for an open interval to  avoid confusion with ordered pair.

Comment: So you are looking for resources which suggest unambiguous notational conventions when teaching students in the aforementioned school levels?

Comment: @DavidMitra please see the edit.

Comment: @kaine please see Edit.

Comment: @Maesumi: Um, I apologize for asking, but under which syllabus are the textbooks you want edited.

Comment: @DanielRust yes

Comment: @Nick I am not sure if I understood your question. I do not have any syllabus in mind. I am looking for discussions on the notations themselves, and how they help or hinder understanding.

Comment: This would be a weird idea. Think along the lines "There're 14 competing standards in EU for charger plugs for cell phones. Let's develop a universal one that everyone will use! 4 years later: there're 15 competing standards in EU for charger plugs for cell phones."

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/news-room/content/20131219IPR31414/html/Common-charger-for-all-mobile-phones-on-the-way

Comment: @Thomas : thanks for the link! I heard about a similar initiative at least a decade ago (and I heard the joke ~5 years ago). Interesting enough, they are still trying to enforce a standard charger plug. As the Russian proverb goes, they are tripping on the same rake twice (at least thrice, hehe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it would be hard to get all math teachers to agree on a common notation. Some prefer $(a,b)$ for the open interval and will probably argue vigorously for that use while others will argue that we should use $]a,b[$ for the interval. This is not just a "problem" with simple things, but there is even disagreements in advanced studies.

The solution (IMO) is to teach the students to think abstractly. Teach the students to be comfortable with changing notation. You see this, for example, in calculus with the notation for derivative. Here we have, for example, $f'(x)$ for the derivative of a function and we have $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$. Neither are bad or good, but work well in certain situations.

This also emphasizes the importance (IMO) that the teacher defines notation. The teacher can't assume that everyone understands that $]a,b[$ means the open interval.

All that said, you could still ask the question as to how using certain symbols and notation is related to learning. Are more symbols for example the best way to go? Or should we push towards writing down statements using words?

For this you could try to search journals for articles on: symbols, notation, mathematics, learning.

I did a quick search and found these few sources that might/might not be worth looking at:

- Greek or not: the use of symbols and abbreviations in mathematics.(Report), The Australian mathematics teacher [0045-0685] Quinnell, Lorna yr:2012 vol:68 iss:2 pg:3
- There Is More to Mathematics than Symbols, Mathematics teaching [0025-5785] Rivera, Ferdinand yr:2010
- Notation as a tool of thought,
  Iverson, Kenneth, E. Ashenhurst, Robert (Editor),
  Communications of the ACM, Aug. 1980, Vol.23(8), pp.444-465
- Using children's representations to investigate meaning-making in mathematics
  Macdonald, Amy
  Australasian Journal of Early Childhood, June, 2013, Vol.38(2), p.65(9)